# Keep Labels in EXPSS Summary

Tags: r

I have a data for multi-response table,for understanding multiple response question please check

https://www.harvestyourdata.com/fileadmin/images/question-type-screenshots/Grid-multi-select.jpg

so i am trying to create summary for this kind of questions

Anyway, from a data perspective, this kind of data is usually stored in wide format where each row*column combination is one variable, which is 0/1 coded (0 if the survey participant doesn't check the box, 1 otherwise).

```
data<-data.frame(
  gender = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2),
  sector = c(3,3,1,2,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,2,1,4,2,3,4,4,4,3,1,2,1,5,5,4,3,1,4,5,2,3,4,5,1,4),
  col1=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1),
  col2=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
  col3=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1),
  col4=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  col5=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
)

the labeling below was done already

data$gender<-factor(data$gender, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Male","female"))
data$sector<-factor(data$sector, levels=c(1,2,3,4,5), labels=c("TX","CA","NY","LA","WA"))
data$col1<-factor(data$col1, levels=1, labels="Sales")
data$col2<-factor(data$col2, levels=1, labels="OPS")
data$col3<-factor(data$col3, levels=1, labels="Management")
data$col4<-factor(data$col4, levels=1, labels="HR")
data$col5<-factor(data$col5, levels=1, labels="Ware-housing")

library(expss)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(flextable)

data1 <- data
var_list <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
first_col_param <- "col1"
second_col_param <- "col5"
grouping_var <- "sector"

tab_multi_cross <- function(data,var_list,first_col_param,second_col_param,grouping_var,total_var){ 
  
    total_col <- ifelse(total_var== TRUE,1,0)
  grouping_var <- rlang::parse_expr(grouping_var)
  data1<-data[var_list] %>% as.data.frame()
  data2 <- data %>% select(all_of(grouping_var))
  var_lab(data2[[grouping_var]]) <-""
  #var_lab(data1[1]) <- ""
  #var_lab(colnames(data1)[ncol(data1)]) <- ""
  subset_data <- cbind(data2,data1)
  tab1 <- eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("tab_cells(subset_data,mdset(",
                                        first_col_param ," %to% ",second_col_param,"))"))) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), subset_data[1]) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% tab_pivot()
  tab1 <-  as.data.frame(tab1)
  tab1[which(tab1[,1]=="#Total cases"),1] <- "N"
  setnames(tab1,"row_labels"," ")
  tab1[is.na(tab1)] <- 0
  tab1 <- tab1 %>%
    mutate(
      across(
        .cols = where(is.numeric),
        .fns = ~ round(.x, digits = 1)
      )
    )
  tab1[tab1 == 0] <- '--'
  mask_indices <- sapply(tab1, function(x) x[length(x)] %in% c(3, 4, 5)) %>%
    which()  
  tab1[, mask_indices] <- "--"
  tab1[-nrow(tab1), -c(1, mask_indices)] <- sapply(
    tab1[-nrow(tab1),-c(1, mask_indices)], function(x) # --- (2)
      ifelse(x != '--', paste(format(as.numeric(x), nsmall = 1), "%"), x)) # --- (3)
  i <- match("N", tab1[,1])
  tab2 <- rbind(tab1[i,], tab1[-i,])
  if(total_col==0){tab2 = tab2[,!grepl("^#Tot",names(tab2))]}
tab2
}
```

due to other function requirement the data is already labelled but the data is giving actual column names , i need labelled names.
do we have any solution where i can get this labelled names in summary below

output summary is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEvF9.png)

but it should be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrw2O.png)

so for getting variable i am applying labels again but i have more that 300 summaries like this and it will take too long to apply labels again. do we have any solution where we don't need to apply labels again to get a desired output.

```
data <- apply_labels(dat,
                      col1 = "Sales",
                      col2 = "OPS",
                      col3 = "Management",
                      col4 = "HR",
                      col5 = "Ware-housing"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `mdset` you don't need to convert variables to factors. You need to set variable labels on them:

```
library(expss)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(flextable)

data = apply_labels(data,
                    col1="Sales",
                    col2="OPS",
                    col3="Management",
                    col4="HR",
                    col5="Ware-housing",
                    col6="Admin"
                    )

data1 <- data
var_list <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6")
first_col_param <- "col1"
second_col_param <- "col6"
grouping_var <- "sector"

grouping_var <- rlang::parse_expr(grouping_var)
data<-data[var_list] %>% as.data.frame()
data2 <- data1 %>% select(all_of(grouping_var))
var_lab(data2[[grouping_var]]) <-""
subset_data <- cbind(data2,data)
tab1 <- eval(parse_expr(paste0("tab_cells(subset_data,mdset(",
                               first_col_param ," %to% ",second_col_param,"))"))) %>% 
    tab_cols(subset_data[1]) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% tab_pivot()
tab1 <-  as.data.frame(tab1)
setnames(tab1,"row_labels"," ")
tab1[is.na(tab1)] <- 0
```

UPDATE - solution with factors.

if you need to stick with factors than insead of `mdset` you should use `mrset`.

Comment: yes, i am applying the same way, but due to other summary requirements i have to declare labels prior.the database i read is already labelled but still i am getting the actual columns name.do we have any solution where i doesn't need to give labels again

Comment: this is a function , i am applying like below in my chunks , but the data is already labelled , i don't want to label again 
```
data = apply_labels(data,
                    col1="Sales",
                    col2="OPS",
                    col3="Management",
                    col4="HR",
                    col5="Ware-housing",
                    col6="Admin"
                    )
tab_multi_cross(data = data,var_list=c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6"),first_col_param ="col1",second_col_param = "col1",grouping_var = "sector" )
```

Comment: @rjunkie2 Could you provide example of your data? `str(data[, paste0("col", 1:6)])` If you have variable label they should be shown with `mdset`. Try to start with clean session and load expss after the all other packages.

Comment: I have updated example and also I have updated reproducible sample please check

Comment: @rjunkie2 What is the source of your data? Do you have labels on your data just after loading?

Comment: yes the labeling  was done already that i have sourced in my RMD file because of other function requirement. yes labeling was done already just after loading data.

Comment: @rjunkie2 At which line of your code you lose your labels?

Comment: in this line itself
tab1 <- eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("tab_cells(subset_data,mdset(",
                                        first_col_param ," %to% ",second_col_param,"))"))) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(), subset_data[1]) %>% 
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% tab_pivot()

Comment: @rjunkie2 Sorry, but it is impossible - this line doesn't modify your original data. Try `data = expss::add_labelled_class(data)` just after the loading data.

Comment: still no solution, so let me explain you  more, i have read the questionnaire survey data the i have labelled data the same way i have labelled in my reproducible example.

then i am sourcing both (labelled file and function file) in my RMD file , then for creating chunks for output it should the labelled name  in output summary but its giving exact column name . 
so for getting labels i have to use "apply_labels(data)"  again for getting labels in rows.
but its more time taking (the chunks i will have more than 250 always)

i have also updated the full function i have created for

Comment: may be now you can have more idea or solution for my problem..................

also if you have any other function to do that please let me know.

Comment: @rjunkie2 If you insists of using factors you need to change `mdset` to `mrset`. In this case there is no need in `apply_labels`.

Comment: yes it works now, please update the same in your answer so that i can close it thanks again for your help, sometimes a little things can take long time